# How can I set "echo" off on user input? (python)

Tags: python, window, raw-input

Window, getpass doesn't work.

```
"message"
return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

is there other way?

Comment: It depends on **where** are you executing this code.

Comment: Getpass on Windows 7 (and any other system for that matter) fails in IDLE but works in Windows console. It is best not to rely on it though. Build some kind of dialog (easy to do with built-in module Tkinter) that prompts for input and shows some other character instead of the text the user typed.